# Como deixar gráfico responsivo com Highcharts?

Tags: react, gráfico, highcharts

Estou usando React e Highcharts para um projeto e quero saber como deixar este gráfico abaixo responsivo?

Tentei colocar maxWidth por volta do componente, mas não obtive êxito.

[image: Quero que ele ocupe toda a div branca respondivamente]

Quero que ele ocupe toda a div branca responsivamente.

Còdigo do gráfico:

```
function updateChart(healthscore) {
  return {
    chart: {
      renderTo: "container",
      type: "bar",
      maxWidth: "100%",
      width: 460,
      height: 33,
    },
    title: {
      text: null,
    },
    credits: true,
    legend: true,
    tooltip: true,
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        borderWidth: 0,
        borderRadius: 0,
      },
    },
    navigation: {
      buttonOptions: {
        enabled: false,
      },
    },
    xAxis: {
      visible: false,
    },
    yAxis: {
      visible: false,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      labels: {
        y: -2,
      },
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: "Fill",
        data: [100],
        color: "#e7eaf3",
        grouping: false,
        enableMouseTracking: false,
      },
      {
        name: "Percentage",
        data: [healthscore],
        color: "#2ecc71",
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false,
          inside: true,
          align: "center",
          format: "{point.y}%",
          style: {
            color: "white",
            textOutline: false,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  };
}
```

Código do component do gráfico:

```
<div className={styles.healthScore}>
  <HighchartsReact
    className={styles.charts}
    width={192}
    height={192}
    title={"Em alerta"}
    highcharts={Highcharts}
    options={updateChart(asset.healthscore)}
    allowChartUpdate={[true, true, true]}
  />
</div>
```

Comment: `width: 460` ->  você tentou colocar algum valor em unidades `vw`?

Comment: @CmteCardeal tentei, mas não obtive sucesso também

Comment: E o `width` desse componente `HighchartsReact`? É em unidades absolutas, tipo `px`?

Comment: Não sei dizer. Esse width do component nem funciona.

Comment: Acho que vou implementar outra forma de mostrar esse dado. O que devo fazer com esta pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

Se você fixar o width e o height vai atrapalhar. Na div que envolve a tag do highCharts você pode colocar uma class e acrescentar:

```
.graficos {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grafico {
    width: 700px;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

assim ela vai ter 700px ou mais

```
<div class="graficos">
   <div class="grafico">
      <HighchartsReact ... />
   </div>
   <div class="grafico">
      <HighchartsReact ... />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não funcionou. Os charts ainda continuam da mesma forma.